# Downloading uploaded file php

Tags: php, file, yii, download, upload

I'm new to yii framework and we have a project in school about uploading and downloading files and I kind of need some assistance...

I followed this [link](http://www.saidur-rahman.com/how-to-upload-file-in-yii-framework/) as a sample exactly as it is and it really does upload to the uploads folder in yii but now I'm trying to download it using this code in my view:

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
    $media = Document::model()->findByPk($id);
    $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../uploads';
    $name = $media->doc_file;

    Yii::app()->request->sendFile($name, file_get_contents($path."/".$name));
```

but when it downloads, it wont open because the file format is not supported... any idea how I can

Comment: Have you tried setting up the `mime_type` (third argument: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#sendFile-detail)?

Comment: I haven't but is this about the file type? because I have that in the table and I tried downloading a jpg file I uploaded and it wont open but when I check the settings its jpg.

Comment: Then the problem is at upload. If you cant open the uploaded files, your files are messed up during upload. Can you provide the upload code?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little modification on your code. Pass the id through the url on the view and that will hit the download action inside your controller. You should be good to go with this

```
public function actionDownload($id)
{
    $media = Document::model()->findByPk($id);
    $path = Yii::app()->request->baseURL . '/uploads';

    $file = $path . '/'.$media->doc_file;

    if (file_exists($file)) {    
     return Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile($name, @file_get_contents($path));
    }else{
        //throw an error here
    }

}
```